# INSERT INTO using the RETURNING values from another INSERT

Tags: postgresql, insert

I'd like to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2(name)
  INSERT INTO table1(name, address) VALUES ('me', 'home')
  RETURNING name;
```

And then I would expect a new record in table2 with `'me'` in `name`. This would work fine with a `SELECT` returning the values, but I'm having trouble with the nested insert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [data modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with t1 (name) as (
  INSERT INTO table1 (name, address) VALUES ('me', 'home')
  returning name
)
insert into table2 (name)
select name 
from t1;
```