# Inserting multiple values into multiple tables with generated foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, query, foreign-key

Let's say I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  content text NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE bar (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  owner text NOT NULL,
  metadata text NOT NULL,
  foo_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES foo
)
```

I now wish to deep clone all `bar` rows with a specific `owner` such that I also clone the associated `foo` rows.

The issue is that I cannot figure out how to associate the newly generated `foo.id` with the old `bar` that the new `foo` row is based on. I need that association when constructing a new `bar`, as it should consist of the old `bar.metadata` and the new `foo.id`.

I want to write something like

```
WITH old_bars AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM bar
  WHERE owner = 'Alice'
), new_foos AS (
  INSERT INTO foo (content)
  SELECT foo.content
  FROM foo, old_bars
  WHERE old_bars.foo_id = foo.id
  RETURNING foo.id AS new_foo_id, old_bars.id AS old_bar_id -- This doesn't work
)
INSERT INTO bar (owner, metadata, foo_id)
SELECT 'Bob', old_bars.metadata, new_foos.new_foo_id
FROM old_bars, new_foos
WHERE old_bars.id = new_foos.old_bar_id
```

but as noted in the comment, this is not valid Postgres SQL as `old_bars` is not in scope for the `RETURNING` part of `new_foos`.

Is there a decent way to achieve this in PostgreSQL 15?

When looking at some previous posts(1,2), they all seem to be about inserting a single `bar` and `foo` as it were. In that case, it is easy to figure out which `new_foo_id` to insert into bar, as there is only one to choose from.

Erwin's answer in (3) section "INSERT missing FK rows at the same time" seemed promising. However, I cannot figure out how to apply it to my case. The issue is that `foo` itself doesn't really have an equivalent to `type` to join on. I could join on `content`, but I would like to avoid that as `content` can be quite large and heavy (in reality, it is not a text but a geometry from PostGIS), and it feels weird to first construct the new foo row, then forget about it, and then search for it again using its payload value. This also (somewhat) breaks in the case that `content` is the same for two `foo`s.

One approach I had thought about, was ensuring that `old_bars` and `new_foos` had a consistent ordering somehow, and then merge the two tables based on this ordering (similar to the `zip` function known from functional languages). This however feels very hacky and un-SQL like, which made hesitant to pursue it further.

Another approach would be to perform multiple queries, and then associate `new_foo_id` with `old_bar_id` in the program that calls the database, rather than inside the database. In some ways, this is what I have done in similar situations, e.g. bulk insert, where I can supply the different values as arrays, and I can ensure that these arrays are consistently ordered.

All in all this looks like a commonish problem I expect many people to have encountered over the years and I feel like I am missing some obvious tool or code pattern to solve it.

Referenced posts:

- (1) [INSERT INTO using the RETURNING values from another INSERT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132541/insert-into-using-the-returning-values-from-another-insert)
- (2) [Inserting into multiple tables with a foreign compound key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295532/inserting-into-multiple-tables-with-a-foreign-compound-key)
- (3) [How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key)

EDIT: Here is some example data and the state I would like to a "deep clone" to produce.

`foo` before deep clone of 'Alice' to 'Bob':

```
  id  |           content           
------+-----------------------------
  101 | Sing, O goddess
  102 | the anger of Achilles
  103 | son of Peleus
  104 | that brought countless ills
  105 | upon the Achaeans
```

`bar` before deep clone of 'Alice' to 'Bob':

```
 id |  owner  | metadata | foo_id 
----+---------+----------+--------
  1 | Alice   | abc      |    101
  2 | Alice   | def      |    102
  3 | Charlie | ghi      |    103
  4 | Alice   | jkl      |    104
  5 | Charlie | mno      |    105
```

`foo` after deep clone of 'Alice' to 'Bob':

```
  id  |           content           
------+-----------------------------
  101 | Sing, O goddess
  102 | the anger of Achilles
  103 | son of Peleus
  104 | that brought countless ills
  105 | upon the Achaeans
  106 | Sing, O goddess
  107 | the anger of Achilles
  108 | that brought countless ills
```

`bar` after deep clone of 'Alice' to 'Bob':

```
 id |  owner  | metadata | foo_id 
----+---------+----------+--------
  1 | Alice   | abc      |    101
  2 | Alice   | def      |    102
  3 | Charlie | ghi      |    103
  4 | Alice   | jkl      |    104
  5 | Charlie | mno      |    105
  6 | Bob     | abc      |    106
  7 | Bob     | def      |    107
  8 | Bob     | jkl      |    108
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Add source/initial data (5-7 rows enough) according to #5, and desired final data state according to #3. With explanations.

Comment: @Akina thank you for linking to that page. I have added example initial and final state as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH insert_into_foo AS (
  INSERT INTO foo (content)
  SELECT f.content
  FROM bar b
  JOIN foo f on f.id = b.foo_id
  WHERE b.owner = 'Alice'
  ORDER BY f.id
  RETURNING id, content
),
enumerate_insertion AS (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM insert_into_foo
),
enumerate_source AS (
  SELECT f.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f.id) rn
  FROM bar b
  JOIN foo f on f.id = b.foo_id
  WHERE b.owner = 'Alice'
)
INSERT INTO bar (owner, metadata, foo_id)
SELECT 'Bob', bar.metadata, enumerate_insertion.id
FROM enumerate_insertion 
JOIN enumerate_source USING (rn)
JOIN bar ON enumerate_source.id = bar.foo_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/G4-fyQEq

Comment: Thank you for this, it helped me solve my issue.

My understanding of how it works is that

1. we ensure that the added `foo`s are ordered the same as the old `bar`s when these `bar`s are sorted by their ID.

2. `foo.id` are generated sequentially so the new `foo`s can be ordered by `foo.id` to get the same order as ordering the `bar`s by `bar.id`.

3. We store these orderings using `ROW_NUMBER()` in the `enumerate_x` tables.

4. We can then join on the `ROW_NUMBER()` to achieve the `zip` functionality I mentioned in my question.